# How can I get Variable from One Page To Other Page withput using navigation In UWP C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

I needed help ..
[ ]

```
        _eMARTimer.Stop();
        _faxTimer.Stop();
        _faxRingtoneTimer.Stop();
```

This is my main page and  I want to excute these method in this page from .cs page which is in second page ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgGG6.png)

[What can I do in IF loop for excute that prog ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOG3j.png)

Please help me to solve this.
Thank You so much for concentration.

Comment: Do you have any other updates for this thread? if the answer is helpful, please consider accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to excute these method in thin page from .cs page which is in second page

For this scenario, you could use mvvmlight `Messenger` to approach. And if the other page and send page are not in the same window. you need set other `page NavigationCacheMode="Required"` in the xaml.

```
 public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent(); 
     Messenger.Default.Register<bool>(this,(s) =>
     {
         if (s)
         {
        _eMARTimer.Stop();
        _faxTimer.Stop();
        _faxRingtoneTimer.Stop();
         }
        
     });

 }
```

**Second Page**

```
 Messenger.Default.Send<bool>(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much but its not working. There did not show any errror but also its not working.

Comment: Have you NavigationCacheMode as Required? And have you add debug point in first and check if the method was invoed?

Comment: Yes, I checked by debug point but I notice that method did not invoed. Is any other way to solve this ?

Comment: Please note Messenger  Register method should be called before invoke send method, in other words, you need declare it MainPage ctor method or OnNavigatedTo method like above.

Comment: Ohh Thank You but with this process May be  we can excute only declare page but If we want to excute multiple page then how can We  do ?

Comment: IN SECOND PAGE 

if (sender.DataContext.ToString() == "YES")
                {
                    GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Send<bool>(true);
                    PageHomesList._PageHomeId = 0;
                    PageHomesList._PageHomeName = string.Empty;

Comment: what's mean that `we can excute only declare page`?

Comment: Sir, I Mean I want to excute this code with multiple page.

Comment: You just call `Messenger.Default.Send<bool>(true)` in other page, it will invoke method that declared in the first page.

Comment: If you want to identify which page call this method, just replace bool parameter with  string, and call send method like this `Messenger.Default.Send<string>(pagename)`,

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your attention and I tried every step which you suggest me but may be there some error form my side. 
Thank you sir❣❣